# Typescript error No overload matches this call for AnyStyledComponent since nextjs 13.3.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

After upgrading to nextjs 13.3.1 i now receive this error in the IDE from a styled component:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(component:
> AnyStyledComponent): ThemedStyledFunction<any, DefaultTheme, any,
> any>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'typeof
> ReactSwitch' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'AnyStyledComponent'.

The code is `InputSwitch.styles.ts`:

```
import Switch from 'react-switch'
...
export const StyledSwitch = styled(Switch)`
...
`
```

I suppose there was some changes in the types.
Which was `any` before is now `AnyStyledComponent` and it stopped working.

How can i convert the `Switch` component to an `AnyStyledComponent` type?

Or any other solution to get this working again is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that the 13.3.1 nextjs release included an update to `@types/react` version: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.3.1

> Upgrade @types/react to latest 18.x: #48645

This introduced a mismatch between the used `react` version and the `@types/react` version.

Syncing and pinning the `@types/react` with the `react` version solved the problem.

package.json:

```
"@types/react": "18.2.0",
```